# Magento 2: Create downloadable CSV

Tags: magento2, csv, download-link

I want to export table content in **downloadable csv format**. In magento 1.x it can be achieve by `_prepareDownloadResponse()` how can we achieve same in magento 2. Looks like this function is missing in magento 2. Is their any alternative for this.

**Please note** that I don't want to use `header()` I am already using this which is working but i want to implement it by magento way as this gives warning at the time of extension upload in Magento connect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try with [`\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory::create()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/FileFactory.php).

Take a look import export module you can see how it works:

*vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Download.php*

```
/**
 * Download sample file action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
 */
public function execute()
{
    ......
    $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        null,
        DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/octet-stream',
        $fileSize
    );
   ......
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more on how to do it with `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory::create()`

Comment: @khoa Thanks for the answer, it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a new answer this is just addition to Khoa TruongDinh answers which helps me lot to solve my issue.

when we use above syntax second parameter would be data which we want to put in a csv.

In my example I have added sample data in function.

`$fileSize` is optional parameter so i skip it.

```
public function execute()
{
    ......
    $heads = "Col1,Col2,Col3";
    $colValues = "valC11,valC21,valC31" . PHP_EOL . "valC12,valC22,valC32";
    $data =  $heads . PHP_EOL . $colValues;
    $this->fileFactory->create(
        'sample.csv',
        $data,
        DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/octet-stream'
    );
   ......
}
```

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Why do you skip `$fileSize`? Just add `strlen($data)` and you have the file size. For big CSV files browsers can show a progress bar if the content length is provided.